# I need help figuring out what happened with my BFGminer overnight

Tags: bitcoin-core, mining-pools, mining-theory, terminology, bfgminer

I'm a newbie to crypto and was experimenting with usb erupters because I was getting into ETH mining with my rig and wanted to test it on something less risky. I ran ck pool for my USB erupter just to see and monitor its temps over a course of time. I ended up getting a message from the pool stating: accepted 000593e0 (usb erupter name) Diff 11.7/10k. I have no idea what this means but my efficiency rose to 12.66 and my accepted shares are at 1. Back of my mind I'm wondering if I lucked out and mining a block but I check my coinbase wallet and I see no BTC. So, im wondering what this means.